# QMail patched. Need to add new user

Tags: qmail

I have a client that just handed us access to their servers after their onsite IT quit.  One is QMail that has been patched.  I think it's https://qmail.jms1.net/patches/validrcptto.cdb.shtml.  But not really sure.

The client's notes read:

> The mail server is a patched and modified version of qmail running on CentOS 7.

> To access the QmailAdmin control panel visit http://*redacted*/cgi-bin/qmailadmin and login with the postmaster account. To access the VqAdmin control panel visit http://*redacted*/cgi-bin/vqadmin/vqadmin.cgi and login with the admin user. Both of these are documented in the KeePass database on the *redacted* server.

> Changes to email accounts must be synchronized to the ValidAuth and ValidRcptto cdb files. The scripts for managing those are in the /var/qmail/bin directory of the mail server.

Adding a user was easy enough.  Next I need to "Synchronize changes to ValidAuth and ValidRcptto cdb files".

Where would I start and what further information might I share?  I'm not strong with Linux scripting at all, but am familiar with Linux overall.

I see a new_authcbd_instructions.txt. Contents are:

```
### The lines below have been scripted
# ./mkauth -m > tmp_users.txt
# cat tmp_users2.txt | cbdmake new.cbd new.tmp
# chmod 640 new.cbd
# chown root:nofiles new.cbd
# cp ../control/smtpauth.cbd //control.smtpauth.bk2 %% mv .new.cbd ../control/smtpauth.cbd
# mkvalidrcptto -c validrcptto.cbd
# mv validrcptto.cbd /var/qmail/control/

## now you can simply do:

# ./makeNewAuth
# ./makeNewVR
```

The tmp_users2.txt isn't touched when I use the scripts pointed out at the end (makeNewAuth or makeNewVR).  mkvalidrcptto is beyond my skill set to read.

However, when I execute makeNewAuth and makeNewVR, I see that I have a new tmp_users.txt file and two new *.cbd files in the ../control folder.

Am I safe to say this worked as intended?

Comment: `Am I safe to say this worked as intended?` - Can the new user(s) log into email? That's the test.

Comment: Yep, I did just verify the new user was able to logon as intended.  This works just fine. My guess is that prev IT modified things after the patch was installed and didn't document.